# Initialize a collection of dataframes with dummy values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of different statistical tests to be performed which resulting values all should be written to separate files.
Therefore I want to initialize a collection of empty pandas data frames
but without showing to many redundant lines in my code.

So far I initialize them all independently but there has to be a better way...who has an idea?

```
pearson_r_df  =  pd.DataFrame(columns=features_list,index=features_list).replace(np.nan, 1.0)
spearman_r_df =  pd.DataFrame(columns=features_list,index=features_list).replace(np.nan, 1.0) 
dcor_r_df     =  pd.DataFrame(columns=features_list,index=features_list).replace(np.nan, 1.0)
```

I would love to have a one-liner like:
df1,df2,df3 = function_which_initizialises_several_dataframes()

Comment: Wrap your three lines in a function and return the three dataframes.

Comment: What issues did you find while writing such a function?

Comment: This should not be the problem but then I would have to define a new function. I am thinking about something like a list/dict comprehension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a comprehension like so:

```
df1, df2, df3 = (pd.DataFrame(columns=features_list,index=features_list).replace(np.nan, 1.0) for _ in range(3))
```